# issues connecting MySQL workbench to Power BI

Tags: mysql, powerbi, mysql-workbench, utf8mb4

I am unable to connect my DB to Power Bi after installing the correct connectors.
Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework.'" The only place I can find utf8mb3 is under System variables > Other > character_set_system everything else is utf8mb4 [utf8mb3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oDPl.png)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6nI2.png)

Unable to change value, have ensured all connectors are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side MySQL database has been converted to MariaDB which caused utf8mb3 errors when establishing connection.

Downgrade MySQL/Net Connector to 8.0.28 and that seemed to fix the issue

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/